# move div based on mousemove when visible

Tags: jquery, perspective, mouseenter

I am currently trying to get a div element to react to mouse move, however when scrolling down a page it keeps tracking and moves the element way off it's origin. I have tried everything I know to get the effect to function only when it's visible in the window, but cannot seem to get it to.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
mousePerspective($(window).width(), $(window).height());

  function mousePerspective(w, h) {
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
      var Xmouse = e.pageX;
      var Ymouse = e.pageY;

      //calc perc
      var Xperc = Xmouse / w;
      var Yperc = Ymouse / h;
      Xpos = Math.floor(Xperc * 100);
      Ypos = Math.floor(Yperc * 100);
      console.info("X Axis : " + Xpos + " Y Axis : " + Ypos);
      Xrev = 100 - Xpos;
      Yrev = 100 - Ypos;

      $(".title__container").css({
        perspectiveOrigin: Xpos + '% ' + Ypos + '%'
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. It's using the CSS translateZ to get an effect.

Comment: can you share a jsFiddle of this?

Comment: JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/MAGiKARtS/74exucgo/64/

updated

Comment: Does this help you: https://jsfiddle.net/74exucgo/74/

Comment: If so, let me know and I will post as answer for you along with what I changed

Comment: It would, but I cannot have position fixed as it’ll be used with a scrolling web page.

Comment: so when you scroll down, you want it to stay near the top of the page, so basically the box will scroll out of view?

Comment: No sorry, if I have two instances of the same element on a page, when I scroll down to the second it’s tracked all the mouse movement prior to it displaying so it doesn’t move from the correct origin, does that make sense?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/74exucgo/75/ New JS Fiddle for you, this is closer to the issue I'm trying to resolve.